# jquery plugin public function

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

This is my plugin

```
(function($){
    $.fn.editor = function(options){
        var defaults = {},
        settings = $.extend({},defaults, options);
        this.each(function(){
            function save(){
                alert('voila'); 
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I want to call function save from outside the plugin. How can I do it ?

Comment: Is this function anyhow related to the plugin or it can be static?

Comment: Is the function save using any closure values from the anonymous method it is defined in?

Comment: yes, the function uses other functions and variables within the plugin closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works best for me.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.editor = function(options){
        var defaults = {},
        settings = $.extend({},defaults, options);
        this.each(function(){
            function save(){
                alert('voila'); 
            }
            $.fn.editor.externalSave= function() {
                save();
            }
        });

    }
})(jQuery);
```

call

```
$(function(){
    $('div').editor();
    $.fn.editor.externalSave();
});
```

Comment: This code would call save on all editors, I'm sure that is not a desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

for example something like this?:

[call method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
var save = function () {

   var self = this; // this is a element of each

};

(function($){
    $.fn.editor = function(options){
        var defaults = {},
        settings = $.extend({},defaults, options);
        this.each(function(){
           save.call(this) // you can include parameters 
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: My intention is to keep function save inside the plugin, and call it from outside